# Let $0 < a \leq 1$ and $s_1 = a/2$ , $2s_{n+1} = s_n^2 + a$ , Then how to show that the sequence is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $0 < a \leq 1$ and $s_1 = a/2$ ,    $2s_{n+1} = s_n^2 + a$   , Then how to show that the sequence is convergent.

My Try : I have tried to find out $s_{n+1} - s_n$ and try to understand the nature of the sequence. I got that if $a >1$ then the sequence would be monotonically increasing. But we can not say anything when $a<1$. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Same thing here. Manipulate $s_{n+1} - s_n$, maybe try a different manipulation.

Comment: I would start with assuming that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n+1}=g$$

Comment: Why you would start like this when convergence is to be proved?@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case $0<a<1$ you can proceed in two steps:

1) Prove by induction that $s_n < 1- \sqrt{1-a}$.

Namely, this is easily proved for $n = 1$; if we assume that the inequality holds for some $n$, then
$$
s_{n+1} = \frac{s_n^2 + a}{2} < \frac{(1-\sqrt{1-a})^2+a}{2} = 1 - \sqrt{1-a}.
$$

2) Show that the sequence $(s_n)$ is monotone increasing.

Indeed
$$
s_{n+1} - s_n = \frac{s_n^2 -2s_n + a}{2} > 0,
$$
since $x^2 - 2x + a > 0$ for $x < 1-\sqrt{1-a}$.

Comment: 10k upvotes congrats @Rigel

Comment: Alternately, you can also show that $s_n$ is bounded and has a unique limit point. This is somewhat easier to show : I was writing an answer when yours came up.

Comment: Sorry, I have done an error, now I have corrected the proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Bounded:**

Let's prove by induction that 
\begin{equation}
 0 < s_{n+1} < 1
\end{equation}
The base case is obvious. Now assume $0 < s_n < 1$, hence
\begin{equation}
 0 < s_n^2 < 1
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
 0 < a < 1
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 0 < s_n^2 + a < 2
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
 0 < s_{n+1} = 0.5(s_n^2 + a) < 1
\end{equation}

**Monotone:**

Now let's prove by induction that $s_{n}$ is increasing. $s_1 < s_2$ is obvious. Then, assuming 
$s_{n-1} < s_n$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 s_{n-1}^2 + a < s_n^2 + a
\end{equation}
We get
\begin{equation}
 s_{n} < s_{n+1}
\end{equation}
So, the recursion must converge.

Comment: The last step is also a proof by induction, so the first step must be proved separately (but that is trivial; it should simply be mentioned somewhere).

Comment: yes isn't that what i did ?

Comment: Not quite. See my edit to see what I meant.

Comment: i still don't see what you mean. Each induction procedure was carried out separately.

Comment: You were missing the "base case" for monotonicity: the trivial observation that the first step ($s_1<s_2$) is true.

Comment: missing "$s_1 < s_2$" made you think that i was carrying both induction procedures together ? I think it was easier to say that "you're missing the base case in the second induction proof".. In all cases, thanks.

Comment: No, they are separate inductions. You did mention the "base case" in the first one, but didn't say anything about the "base case" in the second induction. Every induction proof must include its own base case.

Comment: looks like we're not getting each other ..

Answer (score 0):

First, $s_{2} = \frac{a + s_{1}^2}{2}>s_1=\frac{a}{2}$, and for $n\geq 2$
$$s_{n+1}-s_n=\frac{a + s_{n}^2}{2}-\frac{a + s_{n-1}^2}{2}=\frac{(s_n-s_{n-1})(s_n+s_{n-1})}{2}>0.$$
So the sequence$\{s_n\}$ is strictly increasing.
If the sequence is bounded, then the limit exists, suppose the limit exists and is $x$,
then it must satisfy $$x=\frac{a+x^2}{2}.$$
If this equation has solution($x=1\pm\sqrt{1-a}$), it must be $$0<a\leq 1.$$
When $a\in(0,1]$, we prove the sequence is bounded.
By induction if $0<s_n<1-\sqrt{1-c}$ (you can check that $s_1<1-\sqrt{1-a}$), then
$$s_{n+1} = \frac{a + s_{n}^2}{2}<\frac{a+(1-\sqrt{1-a})^2}{2}=1-\sqrt{1-a}.$$
So when $a\in(0,1]$, the limit is $1-\sqrt{1-a}$.